# Joomla module dropdown select email for contact form

Tags: joomla

I need a contact form which allows the user to choose the option as a drop down list the departments to contact by email... depends on the drop down list choose the email should go to that department.
I have already installed that RSForm Pro, but that doesnt not seem to be the one I am looking.

Comment: Which Joomla version? The built-in contact form changed quite a bit. In 1.0, 1.5 it couldn't be comfortably extended without minor core changes but in later versions you can change form field or add custom form fields rather easily with a content plugin e.g...

Comment: Where are the e-mails (which database table) that you want to populate the dropdown?